# apt-get install fails with error "Unable to locate package"

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm getting the error message that the system is not able to locate the package kamailio.

I navigated the repo on that site and I can see that there is a kamailio package, but it's located under http://repo.pouf.org/raspbian/pool/main/k/
folder.

I've also tried to change the sources.list file to read:

```
deb http://repo.pouf.org/raspbian/dists/ wheezy main
```

But that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Please clarify that you are indeed talking about `/etc/apt/sources.list` and that you ran `sudo apt-get update` after modifying the file (which is not mentioned in those instructions oddly enough).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like you just haven't updated your package lists, this is missing from the link that you gave -

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This should download the list files from the repos in `/etc/apt/sources.list` so that `apt-get install` knows what packages to look for.

Note also that you should do this regularly as the repository will change over time. In particularly do it before installing software if it hasn't been done for a while!

Comment: doh!  that was it.  it's happily installing. I'll accept as the answer as soon as the site allows.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

some more handy information. You can use the following command to see the files associated with a package(if a package is already installed).

`$ dpkg -L kamailio`

if the package is not installed, the above command returns

`Package 'kamailio' is not installed.`